# Combine JSON objects from multiple rows into a single object

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, for-json

```
CREATE TABLE t(Id int, typee nvarchar(50), jsonStr nvarchar(max));
INSERT INTO t(Id, typee, jsonStr) VALUES
(3786, 'APV', '{"1":1,"3":3,"4":24,"5":95}'),
(3786, 'VN', '{"1":3,"5":25}');

-- Expected result
-- {"APV": {"1":1,"3":3,"4":24,"5":95}, "VN":{"1":3,"5":25} }

SELECT Id,(
    SELECT CASE WHEN typee = 'VN'  THEN jsonStr END AS [VN]
         , CASE WHEN typee = 'VO'  THEN jsonStr END AS [VO]
         , CASE WHEN typee = 'APV' THEN jsonStr END AS [APV]
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE x.Id = t.Id
    FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) AS TEST1

FROM t
GROUP BY Id
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=80a25972ad80d01b0fc0f39cc8f9fcc9)

I would like to get the outuput like:

```js
{
  "APV": {
    "1": 1,
    "3": 3,
    "4": 24,
    "5": 95
  },
  "VN": {
    "1": 3,
    "5": 25
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing JSON and then formatting returning it further as JSON. You would need to store non-JSON data to do it the way you want. Therefore it seems easier to treat it as a string:

```
SELECT t.id,
       '{' + STRING_AGG( '"' +t.typee + '": ' + t.jsonStr,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY typee) + '}'
FROM t
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Using `FOR XML PATH`:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       '{' + STUFF((SELECT ',"' + t2.typee + '": ' + t2.jsonStr
                    FROM t t2
                    WHERE t2.Id = t1.id
                    FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,'') + '}'
FROM t t1
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Comment: But I can not use STRING_AGG. because of my SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Yes, thought it was 2016 it was added, but that was `STRING_SPLIT`; not finished my coffee yet. You'll need to use the `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` method. (will add shortly anyway)

Comment: Added `FOR XML PATH` method, @Arooran .

Comment: I will use XML Path. Good solution as well. +1

Comment: STUFF function second parameter should be 1 not 2

Answer (score 2):

`FOR JSON` will treat a string as a string even if it represents valid JSON. You need to use `JSON_QUERY` to convert a JSON string to an actual JSON object. `MIN` is required to combine multiple rows to one:

```sql
SELECT Id, (
  SELECT JSON_QUERY(MIN(CASE WHEN typee = 'APV' THEN jsonStr END)) AS [APV]
       , JSON_QUERY(MIN(CASE WHEN typee = 'VN'  THEN jsonStr END)) AS [VN]
       , JSON_QUERY(MIN(CASE WHEN typee = 'VO'  THEN jsonStr END)) AS [VO]
  FROM t AS x
  WHERE x.id = t.id
  FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)
FROM t
GROUP BY Id
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=07ffc8475ee2381ca15dc7a43eb6fdd7)